# catch не получает ошибку из блока try

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код:

```
try {
x.chat({
 message: message.content, 
},"ru" ).then(reply => { 
//код
})
}
catch (e){
   console.log(e)
 }
```

но catch не перехватывает ошибки после .then, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 4):

try/catch работает в паре с async/await, если вы пишете через .then, то и ошибки должны отлавливать с помощью .catch

async/await:

```js
try {
   const reply = await x.chat({message: message.content}, 'ru')
}
catch (e){
   console.log(e)
}
```

.then

```
x.chat({message: message.content}, 'ru')
.then(reply => ...)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```